# user not defined for onAuthStateChanged in Firebase with custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I built a custom hook to get a user from firebase:

```js
export function useAuth() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if (user === null) {
        setCurrentUser(null);
      } else {
        const u = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid));
        const name = u.data().name;
        setCurrentUser(user === null ? null : { ...user, name: name });
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return currentUser;
}
```

In my components I use it as:

```js
const currentUser = useAuth();
useEffect(() => {
    const localScore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score"));
    setPush(!(localScore[currentUser.name] === tasks.length));
                                  // ^ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
  }, []);
```

I think I get the error, because when the components gets rendered the first time, there is no currentUser. But I load the component after the user logged in (what sets the user), thus I am confused.

I think I need to await the user somehow, but how?

---

From the comments:

I moved my `onAuthStateChanged` to a context, but this is checking the login state only once and is not updating:

```js
const AppContext = createContext(null);

export function AppWrapper({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if (user === null) {
        setCurrentUser(null);
      } else {
        const u = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid));
        const name = u.data().name;
        setCurrentUser(user === null ? null : { ...user, name: name });
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={currentUser}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useAppContext() {
  return useContext(AppContext);
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const currentUser = useAppContext();

  return (
    <>
      <AppWrapper>
        {Component.secure && !currentUser ? (
          <Login />
        ) : (
          <>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </>
        )}
      </AppWrapper>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Every time your call `useAuth()` you're asking the firebase for your user doc again, so even if you used `const user = useAuth()` in a parent component and only rendered your child component when the `user` was set, calling `useAuth()` again in the child component means that your hook will send a request to firebase again to get the logged-in user, it doesn't "reuse" the user obtained by the first call to your hook, if you want something like that then you can consider using [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: _"But I load the component after the user logged in (what sets the user), thus I am confused."_ - can you clarify a little how you are checking if the user has logged in? Are you using `useAuth()` in a parent component and then rendering this component only if the user is set? (so you're calling `useAuth()` in multiple places?)

Comment: @NickParsons yes. In `_app.tsx` I call the user and render either the Login or the `<Component />`. But yes, within a component, I call it again. So using a context would be a good idea.

Comment: I have an equal effect with a context. I updated my question, but know it shows my login all the time, even if I log and see `console.log("logged in");` after `await signIn(...);`